# Network Bonding with WAN and wireless

Tags: wireless, networking, lan

I am still new to Linux Ubuntu and I wanted to know if it is possible to bond a LAN and Wireless internet connection when both of them use static IP addresses.

My current information is:

- LAN:
   `10.0.2.200,  netmask 255.255.255.0, gateway 10.0.2.254`
- Wireless: 
  `192.168.1.210, netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.1.1`

Answer (score 3):

No.  Bonding is something you can do with a server that has two ethernet ports connected to the same network, then you can bond them to increase your aggregate transmission speed.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a future answer. Version 13.04 includes network bonding. Very easy to use and you can select each real network connection that will be part of the virtual (bond) network.

[image]