# Network bonding multiple isp connection

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, internet, network-bonding

Linux novice here... I have 2 Internet connection with 2 ISP providers with 2 NIC.

I tried for a long time to combine these 2 isps connection to use like a single connection.

> Home Connection Number 1:

```
#1st ISP... which is dhcp
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

> Home Connection Number 2:

```
#2nd ISP
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.200.97
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.200.1
dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222 8.8.8.8
```

Now my questions are:

Can I combine these 2 connection as a single one.. I have a server ("Fat piping"...as this concept is not clear to me...and how to setup or what to setup ).. then how I do it ???

If not then can you direct me how can I add load balancing... if one connection is not available the second connection take over...

And overall how can I learn more about linux's networking...

Thanks in advance...

## Update [Solved]

at-last...found a solution `https://github.com/lstein/Net-ISP-Balance`

thanks... lincoln-stein from ubuntu forum `http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214561`

Comment: You might find this useful: http://linux-ip.net/html/adv-multi-internet.html

Comment: Your problem is very similar to the question above.  The technical solution is called "bonding"...  ;-)

Comment: @fabby Bonding is something you can do with a server that has two ethernet ports connected to the same network, then you can bond them to increase your aggregate transmission speed. see http://askubuntu.com/a/216937/159183

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought you were trying to do...  Do you want fail-over only?

Comment: @Fabby thanks for your reply. My query are can I combine 2 network as one? if not, then...how do I load balance that 2 network

Comment: Combine 2 network cards as 1 is what bonding is...

Comment: @Fabby there is a concept "Fat piping" which can be used for combining 2 different network as one... I also used dispatch proxy (which is a node library, but unable to do connection successfully... can you refer me a way to load balance.. these 2 network

Comment: at-last...found a solution

`https://github.com/lstein/Net-ISP-Balance`

thanks...
**lincoln-stein**  from ubuntu forum `http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214561`